# DatastoreV1.Query in Dataflow not using limit

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I have the following snippet

```
DatastoreV1.Query q = DatastoreV1.Query.newBuilder()
  .addKind(DatastoreV1.KindExpression.newBuilder()
    .setName("Example").build())
  .setLimit(100).build()
PCollection<Example> examples = pipeline
  .apply(DatastoreIO.readFrom("example", q));
```

and over 1000 entries from DataStore are returned.  I am using DataFlow SDK 1.3.0.

Comment: It's possible I'm misunderstanding the question.  Is the issue 100 vs. 1000, or 1000 vs. unbounded?

Comment: @SamMcVeety 100 limit vs. more than 100 rows being returned

Comment: Confirmed that this is a bug in the SDK.  Is your query dependent on a sort ordering?

Comment: On what file do you see the bug @SamMcVeety? Are you woking on a pull request? Couldn't find the issue for it on github.

Comment: Yes, we are working on a pull request.  The bug is in DatastoreIO.

Comment: @SamMcVeety Thanks for looking into this! My query is not dependent on ordering.

Comment: @jimktrains Updated the answer.  Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in the Dataflow SDK.  The fix has been [pushed to Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/commit/f341a6f1e123a6520bb7c6e0dcfa1fcea949891d).  Note the following: "*when this limit is set the read from Cloud Datastore is performed
by a single worker rather than executing in parallel across a cluster*."  Thank you for your patience!

Update: the fix has since been [released in 1.4.0](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/releases/tag/v1.4.0).

Comment: I _want_ to limit the number of rows returned.

Comment: Understood, looking into it.

Comment: We identified the bug in the SDK and are working on a fix now.

Comment: Thanks @SamMcVeety! It's live on 1.4: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/releases/tag/v1.4.0

Comment: Thank you!  Updated the answer.